# In Solr MLT Component, Can we able to find why Solr MLT returns particular file?

Tags: solr, morelikethis

I want to use Solr MLT. i want to know why particular document is returned by Solr MLt for my search. For example if some documents is returned there should be some word or phrase match with a parent document. Is there a way in Solr to retrieve those words/phrases due to which MLT returns Similar Documents of the Parent?

Answer (score 0):

According to [SOLR-860](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-860) this information is included in the `debugQuery` information from Solr 3.1 and onwards.